# Focus on click doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to hide placeholder on click, but seems something blocking focus, i try to add css `input:focus:placeholder` ETC.
But nothing, this is my whole code, please try to se if there something in js, that prevent focus state.

[jsfiddle.net/74fnr3k7/](http://jsfiddle.net/74fnr3k7/)

Comment: placeholders disappear as soon as the user starts typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged this question with JQuery, but you didn't include in in your fiddle, so I'm not sure if you're using it. If you are, add these lines to your js and it will remove the placeholder on focus:

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"");
});
```

Make sure you wrap it in a document.ready function ( $(function()... in JQuery). Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4tt77a65/

Comment: yes it's working can you please add code, that on blur it shows up again?

Comment: just replace 'focus' with 'blur' and place your new text within the double quotes of the attr() function. ... .on('blur', function(){ ... .attr('placeholder', 'new placeholder text'); ...

Answer (score 1):

The `placeholder=""` attribute typically vanishes when the user starts typing. If you want to hide the text before the user starts typing, you can use the draft [`placeholder` pseudo-element](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder).

You can hide the text by changing the placeholder's text color.

```
/* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type="text"]:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

/* Internet Explorer */
input[type="text"]:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

/* Edge */
input[type="text"]:focus::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

As @Shaggy pointed out, I didn't include the `::placeholder` without any browser-specific prefixes:

```
input[type="text"]:focus::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

At this stage, I'm not aware of which (if any) browsers support this without a browser prefix. The [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder) states that every browser requires a prefix, because this pseudo-selector [draft status](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#placeholder-pseudo) at the moment. However, adding the selector without prefixes does future proof your code if/when it becomes a standard pseudo-selector.

There are other options that would use JavaScript to change the value of `placeholder=""` for `onBlur()` and `onFocus()` events as well.

Comment: Don't forget the unprefixed `::placeholder` element.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the placeholder on focus of an input field you can use `onfocus` and `onblur` events.

See below for an example:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'placeholder'"/>
```

Comment: nothing, placeholder still here, just dissapear when i start to typing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```css
textarea:focus, input:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="exampleInlineTags" class="form-control token-example-field" name="search" value="" placeholder="placeholder" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right pretraga " id="sonata_search_submit">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
    <span>SEARCH</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing, placeholder still here, just dissapear when i start to typing.

Comment: Just add your JS. It's only CSS and HTML here. **Demo [JSFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74fnr3k7/1/)**

Comment: Please reread the question, Pierrou; it's the placeholder he's looking to get rid of, not the outline.